# What are the conditions for the base invasion to happen?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown, xcom-enemy-within

What are the conditions which must be met before the aliens invade your base? Can it happen again?

When I got raided by the aliens, this was my current story progress:

> **Date:** July 8th. **Difficulty:** Normal. **Alien Storyline:** I raided the alien base some weeks ago and researched the hyperwave beacon, but I hadn't start building the hyperwave relay yet. **Exalt Storyline:** Two missions ago I completed the third covert ops extraction mission.

Answer (score 6):

As far as I know, the invasion triggers 14-21 days after you assault the alien base. I can confirm you do not have to build or research the hyperwave beacon, as it triggered before I did.

Answer (score 2):

Based on in-game dialogue, it should be a one-time event.  I know it can occur as early as June on Classic, and does NOT require researching the Hyperwave Decoder.  I believe but cannot yet prove it's triggered by the first event in your "Alien Storyline" in your spoiler - it happened to me only a few days after that event.

Edit: [Ufopedia.org](http://ufopaedia.org/index.php?title=XCOM:_Enemy_Within_(EU2012)#XCOM_HQ_Base_Defense) confirms it's a one-time event.  Regarding timing: "Base Defense can take place after May and at least until September." It lists no other conditions, so either I'm wrong or they haven't noticed the dependency yet.  I imagine I'm wrong; ufopedia's usually pretty solid.

Comment: Never trust a wiki article without citations.